# Allegro5 C++: Audio sample can't be loaded

Tags: c++, allegro5

I'm trying to insert a song that plays on a loop in my c++ Allegro 5 game. It keeps saying that it can't load the audio.

I have:

1. tried to use .wav and .ogg files, both did not work.
2. put the audio file in the correct directory.
3. created a function to detect the error.
4. initialized `al_init_acodec_addon()` and `al_install_audio()`

> ```
> ALLEGRO_SAMPLE* song = al_load_sample("liar.ogg");
> void game_begin()
> {
>     if (!song)
>     {
>         printf( "Audio clip sample not loaded!\n" );
>         show_err_msg(-6);
>     }
>     //Loop the song until the display closes
>     al_play_sample(song, 1,0,1,ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_LOOP, NULL);
> ```

Basically the console almost always prints out the error message no matter what I do.

Is this a known Allegro 5 problem? I still can't think of a way to fix this...

On a side note, I have tested loading & playing audio in another project file and **it worked**. Is my file cursed? :(

Answer (score 0):

:)
Try to put it in THIS ORDER before loading samples:

```
if(!al_init())
    return -1;
if(!al_install_audio())
    return -2;
if!(!al_init_acodec_addon())  // after installing audio
    return -3;
if(!al_reserve_samples(1))
    return -4;
```

And what do you mean by correct directory?